# Problems searching dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, search

I'm having problems searching data with date fields.

I have a stored Procedure that is performing the search:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearchTraining]
(
  @CourseName VARCHAR(50)= null,
  @TrainingProvider VARCHAR(50)= null,
  @TrainingCost VARCHAR(50) = null,
  @StartDate Varchar(50) = null,
  @EndDate Varchar(50)= null,
  @RowCount int output

)
AS
 BEGIN

  SELECT *  FROM vwTrainingDetails 
  WHERE ( CourseName Like '%' + @CourseName +'%' or @CourseName is null)
  AND ( TrainingProvider Like '%' + @TrainingProvider + '%' or @TrainingProvider is null)
  AND ( Cost Like '%' +  @TrainingCost +'%'  or @TrainingCost is null)
  AND ([Start Date] >=  @StartDate or @StartDate is null)
  AND ([Start Date] <=  @EndDate  or @EndDate is null)


  select @RowCount=@@ROWCOUNT

END
```

I'm passing my parameters as follows:

```
//Create and add a parameter to Parameters collection for the stored procedure.
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CourseName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TrainingProvider", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TrainingCost", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40));


        //string mysdate = (StartTextBox.Text).ToString;
        //Assign the search value to the parameter.
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@CourseName"].Value = (CourseTextBox.Text).Trim();
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@TrainingProvider"].Value = (ProviderTextBox.Text).Trim();
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@TrainingCost"].Value = (CostTextBox.Text).Trim();
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = (StartTextBox.Text);
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value =(EndTextBox.Text);
```

Problem I'm having is that when I run as is the stored procedure does not return anything. 
If I comment out :

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = (StartTextBox.Text);
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value =(EndTextBox.Text);
```

Then it works but without the ability to search using dates.

When I execute the stored procedure from the server and pass in the parameters including dates it works fine.

Can someone help me out and see what I'm doing wrong!!!?

Thanks

Comment: why are you defining dates as text?

Comment: Have you checked the date format you're passing is correct? Also they should be DateTime, not string

Comment: I have tried using DateTime but it still doesn't work

Comment: I would try changing the the type from Varchar to Date as suggested before and then on the app side cast StartTextBox.Text and EndTextBox.Text from string to DateTime

Comment: Could it be the way That I'm passing it from asp.net. If I comment out the dates it works fine...

Comment: @Ulises I have tried casting :Convert.ToDateTime(StartTextBox.Text), still doesnt work

Comment: Test the Stored Proc by running it with the date's you're passing in from the text boxes. I reckon it has something to do with dateformats.

Comment: @rudeovskizebear I've done that, the stored proc returns the correct data when I run it from management studio

Comment: @vitalix for "empty" dates try passing null versus empty string. TextBox.Text will never be null and your check for null will never be true.

Comment: @Ulises Ok I've done a check to search for dates only of the value of the textbox is empty i.e:  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StartTextBox.Text)) this fixes my problem of the other fields not being searched. But as soon as I enter dates it stops working

Comment: Problem Sloved. Thank you all for your comments they all helped. I'm now passing the dates as DateTime also checking the value of textbox so that I know wether to pass null value or not. One extra thing I had to do was change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy works perfectly now. Thanks again everyone

Comment: What is the format are you using in the Database ? Can you illustrate some sample input text from your application and your database table with data

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2008 then you can use the CAST function to convert the parameters @StartDate and @EndDate which are of type string to Date

```
AND ([Start Date] >=  CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) or @StartDate is null)
AND ([Start Date] <=  CAST(@EndDate  AS DATE) or @EndDate is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query in your SP

```
SELECT *  
FROM vwTrainingDetails    
WHERE ( CourseName Like '%' + ISNULL(@CourseName,CourseName) +'%')
AND ( TrainingProvider Like '%' + ISNULL(@TrainingProvider, TrainingProvider) + '%')
AND ( Cost Like '%' +  ISNULL(@TrainingCost,Cost) +'%')
AND ([Start Date] >=  ISNULL( @StartDate, [Start Date]))
AND ([Start Date] <=  ISNULL(@EndDate, [Start Date]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@StartDate Varchar(50) = null,
@EndDate Varchar(50)= null,
```

To this:

```
@StartDate DATE = null,
@EndDate DATE = null,
```

Then change this:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date));
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date));
```

to this:

```
// I don't know the exact format of your date, 
// fill-in this accordingly from your Substring'd textboxes:
int startYear = int.Parse(...); 
int startMonth = int.Parse(...); 
int startDay = int.Parse(...); 

int endYear = int.Parse(...); 
int endMonth = int.Parse(...); 
int endDay = int.Parse(...); 



DateTime startDate = new DateTime(startYear,startMonth,startDay);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(endYear,endMonth,endDay);

MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = startDate;
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = endDate;
```

---

You can also shorten your parameters to this:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName",
    CourseTextBox.Text.Trim());
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainingProvider", 
    ProviderTextBox.Text.Trim());        
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainingCost", 
    CostTextBox.Text.Trim());

MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate);
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate);
```

---

And one more thing, change this `@TrainingCost VARCHAR(50) = null,` to `@TrainingCost NUMERIC(18,6) = null` for example.

And then change this:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
   new SqlParameter("@TrainingCost", SqlDbType.Varchar, 40));
```

To:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
   new SqlParameter("@TrainingCost", SqlDbType.Decimal));
```

And then change this too:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@TrainingCost"].Value = 
     decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text.Trim());
```

Or this:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainingCost", 
    decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text.Trim()));
```

Accordingly, change your stored proc too, this look unusual, a Cost field is money; money should not be handled as string. Convert this:

```
AND ( Cost Like '%' +  @TrainingCost +'%'  or @TrainingCost is null)
```

To this:

```
AND (Cost = @TrainingCost or @TrainingCost is null)
```

Likewise, if you need null, properly handle it:

```
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@TrainingCost"].Value = 
     CostTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ? 
       (decimal?) null :
       (decimal?) decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text.Trim());
```